# Tricky CSS bordering on grid/dashboard layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish some tricky borders around certain elements and am on the fence about the best way to accomplish.

Essentially, I want to create a border to the right of each dashboard element and if there is an element under it add a border below it too.  I'm using the [gridster jquery](http://gridster.net/) plugin for the layout engine.  It uses `<ul><li></li></ul>` structure for each grid item.

So given the following I want to the apply the `|` and `_` to each item.

```
[item]  |  [item]  |  [item]
______     _______

[item]  |  [item]
_____      ______

[     item      ]
```

the issue is these items are 100% customizable by end-users from a column and row spanning aspect.  Additionally, the screen resize can come into account to break them down.

I've got a basic implementation for the right with the last item not having a border via css `:last`.

[image]

Any ideas on what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you add class names to these elements?

Comment: @NicoO - ya I can add classes as need based on column / row / span x / span y

Comment: sorry for deleted answer. I did not fully read the text. So basically you don't know where these items will be. Does the grid give you some indication if a item is over/under a line break?

Comment: no problem, not really ... thats what I was wondering if there was css trick to detect line breaks or something along those lines.

Comment: It would be the best to provide a JSfiddle example for the community to experiment with. Try to emulate the problem. There is no need for it to be pretty. It's hard to give you a hint, if you don't know how the grid is behaving.

Comment: @NicoO ya, I was considering that but I thought the gridster link might be sufficient to show how the grid works.

Comment: It sure is a help. But since you can customise it, a working demo would help a lot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no pure css solution to this. Would you be amenable to a js solution?

Comment: open to anything... note: I'm using angular so I have some pretty advanced techniques available...

Comment: Does your dashboard's ITENS resize automatically to the screen resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the grid uses absolute positioning, we can't really use the sequence of the elements in the DOM for much, which makes a pure CSS solution impossible (as far as I can tell...). I would go with some dynamic CSS based on the dimensions of the grid after tthe user has finished dragging a widget. Something like this:

```
function getGridDimens(grid){
    var dimens = {rows: 0, cols: 0};

    $.each(grid, function(idx, value){
        if(value.row > dimens.rows) dimens.rows = value.row;
        if(value.col > dimens.cols) dimens.cols = value.row;
    });

    return dimens;
}

var $hasRightBorder;
var $hasBottomBorder;

var gridster = $('#gridster ul').gridster({
    /* Your options here */
    draggable: {
        stop: function(e, ui, $widget){

            if($hasRightBorder)
                $hasRightBorder.css('border-right', '');

            if($hasBottomBorder)
                $hasBottomBorder.css('border-bottom', '');

            var dimens = getGridDimens(gridster);
            $hasRightBorder = $('#gridster ul li').not('[data-row=' + dimens.rows + ']');
            $hasBottomBorder = $('#gridster ul li').not('[data-col=' + dimens.cols + ']');

            $hasRightBorder.css('border-right', '1px solid #eee');
            $hasBottomBorder.css('border-bottom', '1px solid #eee');
        }
    }
});
```

I don't have a handy gridster example to test this on, but hopefully you get the general idea, and can adapt it to your needs.

Edit re. comments regarding classes instead of raw css:

```
function getGridDimens(grid){
    var dimens = {rows: 0, cols: 0};

    $.each(grid, function(idx, value){
        if(value.row > dimens.rows) dimens.rows = value.row;
        if(value.col > dimens.cols) dimens.cols = value.row;
    });

    return dimens;
}

var gridster = $('#gridster ul').gridster({
    /* Your options here */
    draggable: {
        stop: function(e, ui, $widget){    

            $('.hasRightBorder').removeClass('hasRightBorder');
            $('.hasBottomBorder').removeClass('hasBottomBorder');                

            var dimens = getGridDimens(gridster);
            $('#gridster ul li').not('[data-row=' + dimens.rows + ']').addClass('hasRightBorder');
            $('#gridster ul li').not('[data-col=' + dimens.cols + ']').addClass('hasBottomBorder');    
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ya I was thinking something like this as a last resort, I was hoping I might be able to get it with pure css or some minimal class additions though.

Comment: You could update the js in my answer to add/remove classes instead of raw css. That would actually make it quite a bit cleaner. For one thing, you wouldn't need to keep track of the elements with borders.